# How can i get several pages from an API in a performat way?

Tags: php, laravel, asynchronous, jobs

The problem is:
I need to get some data from an API. The data is paginated. The endpoints are something like this:

```
api.io/getdata/pvt/orders?per_page=100&page=1
```

I need to get that data and have it on my own application, ready to manipulate.

My application is actually on top of Laravel. I'm retrieving this data with Jobs and Queues and it's taking too long to get the data.

How can i improve its performance?

EDIT

The method is like this:

```
public function send()
{
    Log::info("Starting job FetchOrders:");
    $url_feed = "http://genericapi.com/orders?per_page=100";

    $first_request = json_decode($this->request($url_feed), true);

    $number_pages = $first_request['paging']['pages'];

    Log::info("Number of pages been fetched " . $number_pages);

    for ($i=1; $i < $number_pages; $i = $i + 10) {
        Log::info("Fetching page " . $i);
        $orderUrl = $url_feed . "&page=";
        $this->dispatch(new FetchOrders($orderUrl, $i));
    }

    return response($first_request['facets'], 200)
                      ->header('Content-Type', 'text/json');
}
```

And the handle of the FetchOrders Job is:

```
public function handle()
{
    $data = ['list' => []];
    $request = [];
    for ($i=0; $i < 9; $i++) {
        $url = $this->url . ($this->page_number + $i);
        Log::info("REQUESTING URL:" . $url);
        $request = json_decode($this->request($url), true);

        $data['list'] = $data['list'] + $request['list'];
    }
    Log::info(json_encode($data));
}
```

Comment: SO is a resource for advice for existing problems, not a solution provider. Please attempt a solution, provide a code snippet, and narrow down your question.

Comment: I actually doing it with Jobs and Queues. It's slow. So much slow. Will post some code.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you can do to improve performance.

1. Consider reducing the `per_page` count, do your users really need to look at a 100 orders at once?
2. Try specifying the fields your DB query requests. eg: Instead of `SELECT * FROM` do `SELECT order_number, .. FROM`
3. Try [Eager load](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) related data if there is any
4. Caching can also address performance issues directly, if you are using Repositories, you can implement caching there
5. If you have complex queries, use `EXPLAIN` to understand and optimize them

Comment: 1 - I need to get the data from all the pages and manipulate it. For instance:
I need the best selling product from the orders. To get it i need to look all pages and pass the data through an algorithm.
2 - I don't have access to the queries, i only consume the API :(
3 - I'll see how this apply to the case.
4 - I'll see how this apply to the case.